# Existence of Minkowski units in totally real cyclic fields of prime degree

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Does anyone know of any papers which give results on the existence of Minkowski units in totally real cyclic fields of prime degree? F. Marko has some results for composite degree in his paper "On the existence of Minkowski units in totally real cyclic fields" but I'm more interested in the prime degree case. See https://www.emis.de/journals/JTNB/2005-1/pages195-206.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this [short note](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jmsj/1259943179)  by Brumer and the book [Elementary and Analytic Theory of Algebraic Numbers](https://archive.org/details/ElementaryAndAnalyticTheoryOfAlgebraicNumbers3rdEdition) by Narkiewicz, in particular Section 3.3.